# How to join multiple tables at a time using LINQ to SQL?

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-sql

```
Users:
    userid    name    email
    1         venkat   v@g.com
    2         venu     ve@g.com
    3         raghu    r@g.com

patners:
id   userid   patnerid  status
1     1        2           1
2     1        3           1

location:
id   userid    lat    lon
1     1        12.00  13.00
2     2        14.00  12.00
3     3        14.00  14.23
```

if user sends request as userid=1 then i need to pull his patners [2,3] lat,lon values and their names...
how to achieve this?
thanks,

Answer (score 0):

```
var locations = from u in Context.users
                join p in u.partners
                join l in p.locations
                where u.userid = 1
                select l;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var query = from p in parters
            join u in users on p.userid equals u.userid
            where u.userid == 1
            select new
            {
                //properties of p & u  
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Something on the following line should do it. Also check out the [LINQ 101 samples](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b)

```
var result = from u in db.Users
             join p in db.Partners on u.userid equals p.userid
             join l in db.locations on l.userid equals u.userid
             where u.userid == 1
             select new 
                    {
                      UserId= u.userID,
                      PatnerID = p.patnerid
                    };
```